# How to disable cors for some routes in node js

Tags: node.js, cors

I have mentioned the code that I have used in my code. How can I disable cors for some API like user/*

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (origin.search("^.*"+whitelist+".*$")>-1 || origin.search("^.*"+whitelist2+".*$")>-1) {
                callback(null, true)
        } else {
                callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    },
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
    credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my above question,

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp')
const app = express();

function excepetion_routes(path, fn) {
    var regexp = pathToRegexp(path)
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (regexp.test(req.path)) return next()
        else return fn(req, res, next)
    }
}   

var whitelist = 'https://domain1.com';
var whitelist2 = 'https://domain2.com';
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (origin.search("^.*"+whitelist+".*$")>-1 || origin.search("^.*"+whitelist2+".*$")>-1) {
                callback(null, true)
        } else {
                callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    },
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
    credentials: true
}
app.use(excepetion_routes(['/user/*','/another_route'], cors(corsOptions)))
```